# How to Break table column into different columns using Pivot or in any other way

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to break the columns into different columns. Example table data

Table : Vegetables

```
----------------------
Vname | in kgs |
----------------------
Veg1       |  1.5   |
Veg1       |  2.5   |
veg1       |  1.1   |
veg1       |  2.5   |
veg2       |  11.2  |
veg2       |  13    |
veg2       |  12    |
veg2       |  14    |
veg3       |  1.5   |
veg3       |  1.2   |
veg3       |  1.9   |
veg3       |  1.1   |
---------------------
```

I want my output to be:

```
------------------------
Veg1  |  Veg2  | Veg3  |
------------------------
1.5   |  11.2  | 1.5   |
2.5   |  13    | 1.2   |
1.1   |  12    | 1.9   |
2.5   |  14    | 1.1   |
------------------------
```

Query which I prepared, but my output in getting values all duplicates

```
        select t1.in_kgs as 'Veg1',
               t2.in_kgs as 'Veg2',
               t3.in_kgs as 'Veg3'
     from 
        (select vname,in_kgs from vegetables where vname='Veg1')t1
    left join
        (select vname,in_kgs from vegetables where vname='Veg2')t2 on t1.Vname=t2.vname 
    left join
        (select vname,in_kgs from vegetables where vname='Veg3')t3 on t1.Vname=t3.vname
```

Comment: Is there any column available through which data can be ordered for veg1,veg2 and veg3? or any order is acceptable?

Comment: no order just data is enough

Comment: what if data from order from 3 column changed compare to your given expected output?

Comment: yes it could be, maybe this is the issue which is causing me to get duplicate records. may be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below script-

```
SELECT A.[in kgs] AS Veg1,
B.[in kgs] AS Veg2,
C.[in kgs] AS Veg3
FROM
(
    SELECT Vname,[in kgs],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Vname) RN
    FROM Vegetables WHERE Vname = 'Veg1'
)A
FULL JOIN 
(
    SELECT Vname,[in kgs],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Vname) RN
    FROM Vegetables WHERE Vname = 'Veg2'
)B ON A.RN = B.RN
FULL JOIN 
(
    SELECT Vname,[in kgs],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Vname) RN
    FROM Vegetables WHERE Vname = 'Veg3'
)C ON B.RN = C.RN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` to generate a sequence no per `Vname`. And then use conditional case to group it into 3 diff columns

```
select  max(case when Vname = 'Veg1' then Winkgs end) as Veg1,
        max(case when Vname = 'Veg2' then Winkgs end) as Veg2,
        max(case when Vname = 'Veg3' then Winkgs end) as Veg3
from
(
    select  *, r = row_number() over (partition by Vname order by Winkgs)
    from    Vegetables
) v
group by r
```

Or if you prefer to use the `PIVOT` operator

```
select  *
from    
(
    select  *, r = row_number() over (partition by Vname order by Winkgs)
    from    Vegetables
) v
pivot
(
    max(Winkgs)
    for Vname in ([Veg1], [Veg2], [Veg3])
) p
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using determining id values from 1 to 4 for each vegetable, and then applying `case..when` statements :

```
with v2 as
(
select v.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by [Vname] order by [Vname]) as id
  from Vegetables v
)
select max( case when [Vname] = 'veg1' then [in kgs] end  ) as "veg 1",
       max( case when [Vname] = 'veg2' then [in kgs] end  ) as "veg 2",
       max( case when [Vname] = 'veg3' then [in kgs] end  ) as "veg 3"
  from v2
 group by id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ecb1dd20df7c160195b82780c33b444a)</kbd>